# SearchBarDisplay filtering, but not displaying the correct data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I'm trying to implement a search on my table view. I populate an NSMutableArray called `myArray` from Core Data; then I populate my table view with `myArray`

Then, I have an NSMutableArray called `mySearchArray`. I use this array to display the search results. Here's the code I use for filtering:

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    [self.mySearchArray removeAllObjects];

    for (MyModel *product in myArray)
    {
        NSComparisonResult result = [product.productName compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        [self.mySearchArray addObject:product];
    }
}
```

The problem is that the search doesn't work correctly. When I search for something, I get the picture below.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The filtering is working. For example, if I search the letter "a" and only one of the cell names has an "a", only one cell shows up. The problem is that it doesn't show the cell with "a" in it. It shows only the top cell.

[image: search error]

Comment: Have you tried single stepping through the code with the debugger?

Comment: @PaulCezanne - I have not. If I can be honest, I've never used the debugger. I'm not a complete newbie, but there's still a lot that I'm learning.

Comment: Do it, really, using the debugger should have been step 2 in your learning.

Comment: @PaulCezanne - Thanks for the tip. I'll try some things and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below link. it may help you. It's an example of searchbar.

http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of my table view implementation.

I had this code:

`if (self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)`

When I replaced `self.tableView` with just `tableView`, it worked just fine.

So the correct code is:

`if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)`